# Add discussion to rally card

Tags: rally

I see in several existing rally cardboards that some cards have discussion icons on them. When you click on the discussion icon, it displays the full discussion thread as a "popover" and you can add a comment to the discussion. I have not been able to get this icon, and its associated functionality to appear. Simply adding 'Discussion' to the card fields like this (below) does not work like it does for some members of the model HierarchicalRequirement.

```
var card = Ext.create('Rally.ui.cardboard.Card', {
    style: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '100px',
        top: '400px'
    },
    editable: true,
    fields: ['Name', 'Owner', 'ScheduleState', 'Discussion'],
    record: result
});
this.down('#main').add(card);
```

Answer (score 0):

That functionality should be enabled by default.  Your result that you are passing as the record config- is that an instance of `Rally.data.wsapi.Model`?  As long as it's actually a record (like that you loaded from a `Rally.data.wsapi.Store`) and that model type has a Discussion field (like all artifacts do) it should just work...

Comment: I believe I have everything in place as you mentioned. I am seeing the ScheduleState element and it works as well as the other fields I've tried. I am logging the model to the browser console and it has a populated Discussion object in it. Do I need to get the collection or...? I am able to see the discussion control using Rally.ui.popover.PopoverFactory.bake method, passing in the same model.

Comment: I never did get this to work when creating a rallycard object without a cardboard. It does work as expected for a cardboard specifying 'Discussion' as one of the fields in cardConfig.